# Service Discovery Failed on reconnect with bluetooth device

Tags: android, bluetooth

i am trying to connect a bluetooth device with my android app. so far its working fine.

Now the issue is when my device gets out of range , i am showing one dialog box and asking user to reconnect or not.

sometimes i am able to re-connect with the device and sometimes i do get error i.e.

```
Service Discovery Failed
```

and i really don't know why its happening

```
private class ConnectThread extends Thread {

           public ConnectThread() {

           try {

            bluetoothSocket = bluetoothDevice.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(UUID);


        } catch (IOException e) {

              System.out.println("IO EXCEPTION" + e.getMessage() +"");

        }
      }

        public void run() {

           bluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();

        try {
               // I AM GETTING ERROR HERE
               bluetoothSocket.connect();


        } catch (IOException connectException) {


        Log.d("Exception : ConnectThread -> Run" , connectException.getMessage()+"");

        try {

              bluetoothSocket.close();

         } catch (IOException e) {

        // TODO Auto-generated catch block

          e.printStackTrace();

       }

        return;

      }

     }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

From experience, and actually having the same issue today,

If I was to speculate, I would say your other device, upon disconnection(link loss) does not immediately detect it has disconnected (it can take up to 30 seconds if I remember), or it just behaves badly.

Thus, it does not readvertise the service on SDP (does not open the socket again), so when Android initiates the connection(as client) your server fails - has no open socket.

You should post the other device logs. And try with a different other device - but same Android phone and code!

Again, just a guess.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem; my solution may be specific to the device I am using, but I found that by sleeping the thread for 1000ms between the last communication to the socket and the socket.close(), it would restart successfully.